# How to user jquery to display text when some value is filled into a rails form text field

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

Let's say I have a form and I want to display "Hello" on the page when I fill in a number >5 into a price number_field. How would I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

HTML:

```
<input type="number" name="price_number_field" />
```

JS:

```
$("input[name='price_number_field']").change(function(){
    if($(this).val()>5){alert("Hello!");}
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Pesulap/cy4q3/)

Comment: Where would I put this in the asset pipeline. The field is for a form for create/edit Listing model